# Can't create Custom RBAC in Management group

Tags: windows, azure, rbac

I'm trying to create a custom RBAC (Role) at my Management Group level and it doesn't work.

I receive the following error message: Validation error: Custom role at management group scope is not supported.

I already checked on the internet and It should work.

Do you have any idea about how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What command are  you running? What does you custom role look like?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact error using the Azure Portal, but it worked using PowerShell.

The feature is still in Preview so they might have problems with it every once in a while.

Here are the steps for PowerShell: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-powershell#create-a-custom-role-with-json-template